# Generating windows forms controls dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I am trying to create a form application with customizable "themes" using the abstract factory pattern (just to get some experience with it). I have created an implementation of a theme-factory like this:

```
public class BlueTheme : IThemeFactory
{
    public Button CreateButton() => new BlueButton();
    // ... more controls here ...
}
```

Now I pass an `IThemeFactory` instance through the constructor of my `Form`:

```
private IThemeFactory _themeFactory;

public Form1(IThemeFactory theme)
{
    _themeFactory = theme; // e.g. new BlueTheme()
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

**My question is:** Are there ways make my form use the `IThemeFactory.CreateButton()` method to generate all of the buttons on the form?

Comment: I am thinking about just replacing (mapping) all normal buttons with themed buttons after initialisation, but there must be better solutions, right?

Answer (score 0):

Despite being created by the Windows Forms Designer, the `InitializeComponent()` method is totally normal and can be edited.  It's located in the file: `*.Designer.cs` (where `*` is the name of your class).

The method contains all the constructor calls for your components, but you can go ahead and replace these with your factory method calls.  Note that this will likely prevent you from using the Windows Forms designer to edit your layout, but everything you can do in the designer, can be done by editing the code in the `*.Designer.cs*` file.

Answer (score 0):

As it seemed to be impossible to use a factory to achieve what I tried to do, I decided to style the existing components by looping through them recursively:

```
public abstract class Theme
{
    public delegate void ButtonStyler(Button button);
    public ButtonStyler StyleButton { get; }

    protected Theme(ButtonStyler styleButton)
    {
        StyleButton = styleButton;
    }

    // Apply this theme to all components recursively
    public void Style(Control parent)
    {
        if (parent is Button) StyleButton((Button) parent);
        foreach (Control child in parent.Controls) Style(child);
    }
}

public class BlueTheme : Theme
{
    public BlueTheme() : base(
        button =>
        {
            button.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
            button.ForeColor = Color.White;
            button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        }) {}
}
```

In this example I only implemented the buttons, but any component styling can be easily added, and using a theme is as easy as:

```
public Form1(Theme theme)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    theme.Style(this);
}

private static void Main() {
    Application.Run(new Form1(new RedTheme()));
}
```

Although this works, I'm still curious if this would be achievable with a factory, like explained in the initial question.